# Trying to submit to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Hello I am trying to submit this my app to the app store, after doing proper setup and trying to push to the store, but unfortunately I got this message.

Can someone help ?[image]

Comment: The message is pretty clear. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Paulw11 xcode6 kind of beta version but I was made to know that I can submit my app with that build of xcode.

Comment: Who said that? As the message says you need the released version of XCode 6 or download it from the Mac app store or developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using a beta version of Xcode. In the menu on the Apple left click on Xcode then "About Xcode" and verify the version. From the GUI it seems that you are using xcode 6 beta. 
Download the latest version from AppStore and try again.